# How do I interleave strings in Python?

Tags: python

How do I interleave strings in Python?

Given

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'xyz'
```

How do I get `axbycz`?

Comment: No one is going to help you if you don't show some **effort**. Besides that, **this question can be solved using Google**. I don't like to say it, but in this case it is true: **Google is your friend!**

Comment: Not sure what to call this - I've gone with "interleaving".

Comment: I think I'd call it `zip` -ping ;)

Comment: related: [Most pythonic way to interleave two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34756145/4279)

Comment: @badp : I disagree, `zip` produces couples, but the second string might be shorter : `interleave("abc","12")` should give "a1b2c", possibily one would also like to have `interleave("abcdef","12") = "a1b2c1d2e1f"`. I think the question is legit and google won't give you quicky the most efficient, pythonic method.

Answer (score 16):

Here is one way to do it

```
>>> s1 = "abc"
>>> s2 = "xyz"
>>> "".join(i for j in zip(s1, s2) for i in j)
'axbycz'
```

It also works for more than 2 strings

```
>>> s3 = "123"
>>> "".join(i for j in zip(s1, s2, s3) for i in j)
'ax1by2cz3'
```

Here is another way

```
>>> "".join("".join(i) for i in zip(s1,s2,s3))
'ax1by2cz3'
```

And another

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> "".join(chain(*zip(s1, s2, s3)))
'ax1by2cz3'
```

And one without `zip`

```
>>> b = bytearray(6)
>>> b[::2] = "abc"
>>> b[1::2] = "xyz"
>>> str(b)
'axbycz'
```

And an inefficient one

```
>>> ((s1 + " " + s2) * len(s1))[::len(s1) + 1]
'axbycz'
```

Comment: What to choose? Which one is the "preferably only one obvious way to do it"?

Comment: @gnibbler And this one ? :) ``print ''.join(sum([ [a,b] for [a,b] in zip(s1,s2)],[]))`` . Upvoted though.

Comment: I'd choose "".join("".join(i) for i in zip(s1,s2,s3)) since it's probably the easiest to parse with my eyeballs.

Comment: @eyquem, sum(...,[]) has quadradic performance (because it makes a new list each time it adds an element)

Comment: @gnibbler In the doc: _"sum(iterable[, start]) Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total."_ It doesn't say that a new object is created after each adding of an item rather than an in place adding. But you must be right, because if I do: ``li=[]`` ``print id(li)`` ``tot = sum([ [a,b] for [a,b] in zip(s1,s2)],li)`` ``print id(tot)`` , I obtain **18718112** and **18748560**

Comment: @gnibbler For **reduce()**, it is clearly expressed in the doc: _"Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value. For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5). The left argument, x, is the accumulated value and the right argument, y, is the update value from the iterable."_ That's why I thought that **sum()** was executed differently. I was wrong

Comment: @eyquem, I made the same mistake with sum once here on SO and was admonished by Alex Martelli :)

Answer (score 2):

What about (if the strings are the same length):

```
s1='abc'
s2='xyz'
s3=''
for x in range(len(s1)):
   s3 += '%s%s'%(s1[x],s2[x])
```

I'd also like to note that THIS article is now the #1 Google search result for "python interleave strings," which given the above comments I find ironic :-)

Comment: Stuff like this always happens on SO ;)

Comment: And it still is the #1 google search result for `python interleave strings`

Answer (score 0):

A mathematical one, for fun

```
s1="abc"
s2="xyz"

lgth = len(s1)

ss = s1+s2

print ''.join(ss[i//2 + (i%2)*lgth] for i in xrange(2*lgth))
```

And another one:

```
s1="abc"
s2="xyz"

lgth = len(s1)

tu = (s1,s2)

print ''.join(tu[i%2][i//2] for i in xrange(2*lgth))
# or
print ''.join((tu[0] if i%2==0 else tu[1])[i//2] for i in xrange(2*lgth))
```