# Count overlapping regex matches in Perl OR Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, perl

*This is a follow-up to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9324655/863042). I've learned that finding overlapping regex matches in Python is not straight-forward, so decided to do an additional inquiry to see how Perl and Ruby stand up to this task.*

I'd like to **count** the number of all possible matches of a regex against a certain string. And by "all" I mean that the result should take into account both overlapping and non-unique matches. Here are some examples:

- `a.*k` should be matched twice in `"akka"`
- `"bbboob"` tested against `b.*o.*b` should yield 6

As a reference, here's a Perl one-liner suggested by [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist) - it outputs the correct matches and their count:

```
() = "bbboobb" =~ /(b.*o.*b)(?{push @all, $1})(*FAIL)/g; printf "got %d matches: %s\n", scalar(@all), "@all";
```

The only problem with this is that it eats up too much resources for test cases where the resulting match count is in the order of millions or more. But I understand it is due to the fact that all the matches are first groupped and only counted afterwards. I'm looking for a resource-efficient  solution that **only returns the count**.

Comment: If you have a regular expression in the computer science sense, this can easily be done with an NFA in O(RN) with R and N being the lengths of the regular expression and input strings).

Comment: @Nabb But unless you use RE2 (which you actually can in Perl), you don’t get an NFA.  You have a recursive backtracker.  See the Russ Cox papers.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist) has done all the hard work. If storing the matches and counting them afterwards is eating too much resource, then you could just change the regex-embedded code to just count the matches:

```
my $count = 0;

"bbboobb" =~ /(b.*o.*b)(?{$count++})(*FAIL)/g;

print "got $count matches\n";
```

Comment: Maybe a non capturing group can help speed things up a little as well. Either `(?:b.*o.*b)` or the `/n` flag where supported.