# Insert string into string

Tags: python, string

I have

```
a='Samsung'
b='Nokia'
```

I want to insert b to a, finaly the result is `'SNaomksiuang'`
How to do it in Python with Faster?

Comment: What is `faster`? and what have  you tried?

Comment: Downvote for zero motivation having tried anythign at all

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083829/how-do-i-interleave-strings-in-python

Answer (score 7):

```
In [183]: ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip_longest(a,b, fillvalue='')))
Out[183]: 'SNaomksiuang'

In [184]: a='Samsung'

In [185]: b='Nokia'

In [186]: ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip_longest(a,b, fillvalue='')))
Out[186]: 'SNaomksiuang'
```

Comment: Nice use of chain!  Definitely a nicer solution than my nested joins.  +1

Comment: @NolenRoyalty I would agree but the way it is written here doesn't look so nice and yours looks nicer. However it can be written like this: `''.join(chain.from_iterable(izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='')))`

Comment: @jamylak: I had to include `itertools.` to show OP where the functions come from

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> a='Samsung'
>>> b='Nokia'
>>> ''.join([''.join(i) for i in izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue='')])
'SNaomksiuang'
```