# Use upper and lower cases on a same word

Tags: python, string, uppercase, lowercase

I need to convert a random string into string where upper and lower cases switch at every letter.
Something like THAT or that become ThAt

I tried something:

```
def mom(c):
    c1=c.lower()
    c2=c.upper([::2]
    print(c2)
    return c2
mom("Hello dear")
```

But it only keeps the upper cases.

Comment: yes, forgot to say it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of upper and lower case letters and just mix both.

```
def mom(c):
    c1=c[1::2].lower()
    c2=c[::2].upper()
    return "".join(i for j in zip(c2, c1) for i in j)
print(mom("Hello dear"))
```

Results:

```
print(mom("THAT"))       # prints ThAt
print(mom("that"))       # prints ThAt
print(mom("Hello dear")) # prints HeLlO DeAr
print(mom("HELLO DEAR")) # prints HeLlO DeAr
print(mom("hello dead")) # prints HeLlO DeAd
```

I got the `"".join(i for j in zip(c2, c1) for i in j)` part from here [How do I interleave strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3083894/4577762)