# Read lines from multiple files python

Tags: python

I have a list of files `['file_a.txt', 'file_b.txt', 'file_c.txt' ....]`

I want to read one line from each file and generate a new line by adding them together.

The output should look like:

```
file_a_line_1 file_b_line_1 file_c_line_1.... 
file_a_line_2 file_b_line_2 file_c_line_2....
```

Can `zip` be used to do this?

Comment: Yes, zip is the way to go for this. What do you want to have done if the files aren't of the same length?

Comment: I am not able to find examples of using zip with multiple files (more than 2), if they are not of same length I would like to keep them adding lines from the ones which are still there in the same order.

Comment: Ah, I found a way to fill it, I think. Updating my answer..

Comment: "I am not able to find examples of using zip with multiple files (more than 2)," - What makes you think it would be any different for multiple files?

Comment: Also see my recent answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756145/most-pythonic-way-to-interleave-two-strings/34756161#34756161).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

files = [open(filename) for filename in file_list]

for lines in zip_longest(*files, fillvalue=''):
    print(" ".join(lines))
```

This should also work when the files don't have the same length. I would use izip_longest, if you're on Python 2, instead.

This will leave several spaces between values if some files are exhausted, so you might want to do more complicated stuff than the join, but that's the easier part.

Comment: I didn't know about zip_longest. Awesome!

Comment: Ah, thanks, corrected. I didn't know about zip_longest either before, but in general it's good to look in itertools for iteration questions and functools for functional programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work.  You'd open all the files, then read one line at a time from each of them.  It's unclear what you want to do when one file has no lines left (stop entirely), keep going until all lines have no lines left?

```
file_list = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

fps = []
for fn in file_list:
    fps.append(open(fn, 'w'))
curLine = 'start'

while curLine:
    curLine = ''
    for fp in fps:
        myLine = fp.readline()
        if myLine:
            curLine += myLine + ' '
        else:
            break #can do what you want when you run out

for fp in fps:
    fp.close()
```

Remember to close your file handlers.