# How to zip together 2 Fields in Zapier Code with either Python or Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, zapier

I am trying to interleave 2 fields in zapier code, I have searched for a few hours trying to find a similar question with the answer and the best result i had was with;

[Most pythonic way to interleave two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756145/most-pythonic-way-to-interleave-two-strings?answertab=active#tab-top)

so from that answer, I have put the code in like this;

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GklKO.jpg)

But it keeps coming up with an error or saying that 'the code is good but no output';

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KdtC.jpg)

I have very limited knowledge of coding but the Output I'm after is, in simple forms, to have the quantities next to the name of our products;

Quantity= 1,2,3,4

Product= A,B,C,D

Ideal Output= 1 x A, 2 x B, 3 x C, 4 x D

The input fields have no spaces in, the Products and the Quantities are also separated by Comma's

Can anyone help with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You literally have to define an output variable which must be a JSON object or array. It will serve as an input in any Zap action you define afterwards.

E.g. at the end of your code you can write:

```
output = "".join(zip(l1,l2))
```

or

```
return "".join(zip(l1,l2))
```

See the [code examples section](https://zapier.com/help/code/#code-examples) at Zapier's docs.