# Getting the nth char of each string in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's they I have the list `['abc', 'def', 'gh']` I need to get a string with the contents of the first char of the first string, the first of the second and so on.

So the result would look like this: `"adgbehcf"` But the problem is that the last string in the array could have two or one char.

I already tried to nested for loop but that didn't work.

Code:

```
n = 3 # The encryption number    

for i in range(n):
    x = [s[i] for s in partiallyEncrypted]
    fullyEncrypted.append(x)
```

Comment: can you show whatever code you've tried so far? why didn't it work?

Comment: edit your post with your code

Comment: Looks like homework, so instead of posting an answer I will just point you to   [list comprehension examples](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756145/most-pythonic-way-to-interleave-two-strings/34756226

Comment: Is this homework?  Here you go:  `''.join(*zip(L[0][0], *L[1:]))`.

Comment: `''.join(''.join(y) for y in zip(*x)) + ''.join(y[-1] for y in x if len(y) == max(len(j) for j in x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a version using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

lst = ['abc', 'def', 'gh']
strg = ''.join(''.join(item) for item in zip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=''))
print(strg)
```

to get an idea why this works it may help having a look at

```
for tpl in zip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=''):
    print(tpl)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! But im a bit embarresed that I couldn't solve this for 2,5 hours :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
l = ['abc', 'def', 'gh']
print "".join(filter(None, [i for sub in izip_longest(*l) for i in sub]))
# adgbehcf
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use this:

```
''.join(''.join(y) for y in zip(*x)) + 
''.join(y[-1] for y in x if len(y) == max(len(j) for j in x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Having:

```
l = ['abc', 'def', 'gh']
```

This would work:

```
s = ''

In [18]: for j in range(0, len(max(l, key=len))):
    ...:     for elem in l:
    ...:         if len(elem) > j:
    ...:             s += elem[j]

In [28]: s
Out[28]: 'adgbehcf'
```