# Duplicate strings in a list and add integer suffixes to newly added ones

Tags: python, string, list, performance, duplicates

Suppose I have a list:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And its suffix list:

```
l2 = ['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']
```

I'd like the desired output to be:

```
out_l = ['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_2', 'c', 'c_3']
```

The result is the interleaved version of the two lists above.

I can write regular `for` loop to get this done, but I'm wondering if there's a more Pythonic way (e.g., using list comprehension or lambda) to get it done.

I've tried something like this:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[1]+'_'+str(x[0]+1), enumerate(a)))
# this only returns ['a_1', 'b_2', 'c_3']
```

Furthermore, what changes would need to be made for the general case i.e., for 2 or more lists where `l2` is not necessarily a derivative of `l`?

Comment: related: [Interleaving two lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7946798/4279) and [Most pythonic way to interleave two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34756145/4279)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

#### [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)

You can use a generator for an elegant solution. At each iteration, yield *twice*—once with the original element, and once with the element with the added suffix.

The generator will need to be exhausted; that can be done by tacking on a `list` call at the end.

```
def transform(l):
    for i, x in enumerate(l, 1):
        yield x
        yield f'{x}_{i}'  # {}_{}'.format(x, i)
```

You can also re-write this using the `yield from` syntax for generator delegation:

```
def transform(l):
    for i, x in enumerate(l, 1):
        yield from (x, f'{x}_{i}') # (x, {}_{}'.format(x, i))
```

```
out_l = list(transform(l))
print(out_l)
['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_2', 'c', 'c_3']
```

If you're on versions older than python-3.6, replace `f'{x}_{i}'` with `'{}_{}'.format(x, i)`.

**Generalising**
Consider a general scenario where you have N lists of the form:

```
l1 = [v11, v12, ...]
l2 = [v21, v22, ...]
l3 = [v31, v32, ...]
...
```

Which you would like to interleave. These lists are not necessarily derived from each other.

To handle interleaving operations with these N lists, you'll need to iterate over pairs:

```
def transformN(*args):
    for vals in zip(*args):
        yield from vals

out_l = transformN(l1, l2, l3, ...)
```

---

#### Sliced `list.__setitem__`

I'd recommend this from the perspective of performance. First allocate space for an empty list, and then assign list items to their appropriate positions using sliced list assignment. `l` goes into even indexes, and `l'` (`l` modified) goes into odd indexes.

```
out_l = [None] * (len(l) * 2)
out_l[::2] = l
out_l[1::2] = [f'{x}_{i}' for i, x in enumerate(l, 1)]  # [{}_{}'.format(x, i) ...]
```

```
print(out_l)
['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_2', 'c', 'c_3']
```

This is consistently the fastest from my timings (below).

**Generalising**
To handle N lists, iteratively assign to slices.

```
list_of_lists = [l1, l2, ...]

out_l = [None] * len(list_of_lists[0]) * len(list_of_lists)
for i, l in enumerate(list_of_lists):
    out_l[i::2] = l
```

---

#### [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) + [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

A functional approach, similar to @chrisz' solution. Construct pairs using `zip` and then flatten it using `itertools.chain`.

```
from itertools import chain
# [{}_{}'.format(x, i) ...]
out_l = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(l, [f'{x}_{i}' for i, x in enumerate(l, 1)])))
```

```
print(out_l)
['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_2', 'c', 'c_3']
```

`iterools.chain` is widely regarded as the pythonic list flattening approach.

**Generalising**
This is the simplest solution to generalise, and I suspect the most efficient for multiple lists when N is large.

```
list_of_lists = [l1, l2, ...]
out_l = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*list_of_lists)))
```

---

#### **Performance**

Let's take a look at some perf-tests for the simple case of two lists (one list with its suffix). General cases will not be tested since the results widely vary with by data.

[image]

[Benchmarking code, for reference.](https://gist.github.com/Coldsp33d/76ed10720e529b658874bd00075509fb)

#### **Functions**

```
def cs1(l):
    def _cs1(l):
        for i, x in enumerate(l, 1):
            yield x
            yield f'{x}_{i}'

    return list(_cs1(l))

def cs2(l):
    out_l = [None] * (len(l) * 2)
    out_l[::2] = l
    out_l[1::2] = [f'{x}_{i}' for i, x in enumerate(l, 1)]

    return out_l

def cs3(l):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(
        zip(l, [f'{x}_{i}' for i, x in enumerate(l, 1)])))

def ajax(l):
    return [
        i for b in [[a, '{}_{}'.format(a, i)] 
        for i, a in enumerate(l, start=1)] 
        for i in b
    ]

def ajax_cs0(l):
    # suggested improvement to ajax solution
    return [j for i, a in enumerate(l, 1) for j in [a, '{}_{}'.format(a, i)]]

def chrisz(l):
    return [
        val 
        for pair in zip(l, [f'{k}_{j+1}' for j, k in enumerate(l)]) 
        for val in pair
    ]
```

Comment: I'd recommend the `yield` from the perspective of readability, simplicity, and maintenance, as it's unlikely this is going to be a major bottleneck. (Probably not high enough volume of data, probably not a performance critical app.) The generator is *extraordinarily* straightforward to understand. OP can go back and optimize if it turns out to be a problem. +1

Comment: @user1717828 I'm happy you learned something from this! They are called f-strings and are introduced for python-3.6+. Do take a look at [this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) for more info. Happy learning!

Comment: I don't understand the why `yield from`. Could you add more explanation for that please?

Comment: `yield from` provides a slightly more compact syntax to do the same thing that two `yield` statements do - it _delegates_ the yield process, so you don't need to write a loop over an iterable (or two yield statements as in this case).

Comment: @cs95 The performance comparison is biased since `ajax1234` and `cs0` use `str.format` while other functions use f-strings which are considerably faster (`sruthiV` even uses `+`). So effectively the performance of these functions is degraded by using a less performant formatting option. In order to provide a meaningful comparison the functions need to be updated to use the same formatting option. Also `sruthiV` should use `i//2` instead of `int(i/2)` as it is much more efficient (hence avoiding additional bias).

Comment: @a_guest The answers have been timed as presented. The graph here captures the performance difference between the original answers, formatting choices and all.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list comprehension like so:

```
l=['a','b','c']
new_l = [i for b in [[a, '{}_{}'.format(a, i)] for i, a in enumerate(l, start=1)] for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_2', 'c', 'c_3']
```

Optional, shorter method:

```
[j for i, a in enumerate(l, 1) for j in [a, '{}_{}'.format(a, i)]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
[val for pair in zip(l, [f'{k}_{j+1}' for j, k in enumerate(l)]) for val in pair]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_2', 'c', 'c_3']
```

Comment: You could use a list comprehension instead of zip. Not sure which is faster though...

Comment: If you look at the timings, this is faster than using a list comprehension.  Much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my simple implementation

```
l=['a','b','c']
# generate new list with the indices of the original list
new_list=l + ['{0}_{1}'.format(i, (l.index(i) + 1)) for i in l]
# sort the new list in ascending order
new_list.sort()
print new_list
# Should display ['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_2', 'c', 'c_3']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to return `[["a","a_1"],["b","b_2"],["c","c_3"]]` you could write

```
new_l=[[x,"{}_{}".format(x,i+1)] for i,x in enumerate(l)]
```

This isn't what you want, instead you want `["a","a_1"]+["b","b_2"]+["c","c_3"]`. This can be made from the result of the operation above using `sum()`; since you're summing lists you need to add the empty list as an argument to avoid an error. So that gives

```
new_l=sum(([x,"{}_{}".format(x,i+1)] for i,x in enumerate(l)),[])
```

I don't know how this compares speed-wise (probably not well), but I find it easier to understand what's going on than the other list-comprehension based answers.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ How is it not what was asked? If `l==['a','b','c']` the result is `['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_2', 'c', 'c_3']` as required, and it avoids the use of a `for` loop.

Comment: Eh sorry, didn't read past the first line. HOWEVER, calling sum() on a list is generally frowned upon, it's worse than a loop.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:

```
out_l=[]
for i,x in enumerate(l,1):
    out_l.extend([x,f"{x}_{i}"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier list comprehension for this problem as well:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print([ele for index, val in enumerate(l) for ele in (val, val + f'_{index + 1}')])
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_2', 'c', 'c_3']
```

Note this is just a simpler solution for interleaving the two lists. This is not a solution for multiple lists. The reason I use two `for` loops is because, at the time of writing, list comprehension does not support tuple unpacking.